# gmp.h /mpir.h linker in visual studio 2012 professional

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

I am trying to use gmp.h for C/C++. I am currently working on visual studio 2012 professional. I followed the instructions from the [link](http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-to-install-and-run-gmp-on-windows-using-mpir/). But still I got error messages...

```
1>------ Build started: Project: final, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  final.cpp
1>final.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___gmpz_init referenced in function _wmain
1>final.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___gmpz_init_set_ui referenced in function _wmain
1>final.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___gmpz_out_str referenced in function _wmain
1>D:\New folder\final\Debug\final.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried all possible options but could not got the solution. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was just that I wasn't linking the library.
You need to include the library in the Visual Studio project.

[How to add additional libraries to Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project)