# How to add Botan library to VS 2013 project

Tags: c++, libraries, botan

As the result of installing Botan library I've got these files:

> - botan.dll
> - botan.exp
> - botan.lib
> - and headers with path Include/botan/*.h, one of them is botan.h which must be incuded in

I've added botan.lib and botan.h following  [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4446085/4330546) but I get "botan/botan.h: No such file or directory" error while building project.

```
 #include <botan/botan.h>


   int main()
   {
       Botan::LibraryInitializer init;
   }
```

If I include like this `#include "C:/Include/botan/botan.h"` it's okay with botan.h but I can't rewrite all headers using full path. E.g. botan.h file looks like:

```
#include <botan/init.h>
#include <botan/lookup.h>
...
#include <botan/rng.h>
...
```

So I can't figure out how to include all these files properly.

Comment: The problem has been solved. It was with my VS configuration. Thanks

Comment: I am having similar problems and I would be happy if u contacted me to tell me how you solved this. Thank you.