# Compiling and linking third party libraries in VS 2015

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a C++ project using Visual Studio 2015 I'm trying to link an external library (in this instance `libtins`). The library currently resides on my desktop.

I've tried editing the project settings, under Linker settings, but it doesn't give me any option to include any custom libraries.

How do I do this in VS 2015?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How to add additional libraries to Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4445418/608639)

Comment: Filed as duplicate 3 years later. Damn! That's some nice moderation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

adding to the linker is not enough you need also to add the include library:
properties -> C/C++ ->general -> additional include directories

Comment: don't forget to vote

Comment: Need 15 rep. Will answer some questions and come back to vote :)

Comment: thanks, you remember to vote!

Comment: Solved it for me as well - just wanted to also add that the folders (for me anyway) weren't searched recursively so its important to link the source folder exactly

Comment: Hi, I generate a vs project with `qmake -tp vc` from QT with some additional dependencies, but I find no libs names in `Additional Dependencies` of the vs project, but the vs project do run well. 
Does that mean there is some other methods to add `Additional Dependencies` in vs project?