# Compile and link 3rd party library in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, include-path, fmod

I am fairly new to C programming and I haven't used Visual Studio or a third party library before. I'm trying to do something simple with FMOD and need to link `fmodvclib`, `fmod.h`, and of course `fmod.dll`.

I've put `fmodex_vc.lib` in the additional dependencies and the path to the low level libraries in the include and library directories as well as additional include libraries but when I build it gives me:

```
"cannot open source file "fmod.h"
identifier "FSOUND_SAMPLE" is undefined
Cannot open include file: 'fmod.h': No such file or directory
```

but even weirder is:

```
cannot open source file "stdio.h"
```

here is the code:

```
#include "fmod.h"
#include <stdio.h>

FSOUND_SAMPLE* handle;

int main(void)
{
    int input;

    FSOUND_Init(44100, 32, 0);

    handle = FSOUND_Sample_Load(0, "test.ogg", 0, 0, 0);
    FSOUND_PlaySound(0, handle);

    while (input != 0)
    {
        scanf_s("&d", &input);
    }

    FSOUND_Sample_Free(handle);
    FSOUND_Close();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you add the path of header files to INCLUDE_PATH, you must use #include <filename> instead of #include "filename".  double qoutations must be used for header files that are in the project directory.

Comment: @payman Alright I tried that and got the same errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How to add additional libraries to Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4445418/608639), [Compiling and linking third party libraries in VS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31030556/608639), etc.

Answer (score 29):

To link against third party libraries you usually have to do 3 things:

**1. You have to add the Include Directory.**

In `Project > Properties > C/C++->General > Additional Include Directories`

Click Edit, and enter the path to the directory where the file "fmod.h" is located.

**2. You have to link against the *.lib file.**

In `Project > Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories`, click Edit and enter the path to your library files.

In `Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`, click Edit, add the filename of the library you want to link against (in this case this would be most likely "fmodvc.lib")

**3. You have to provide the *.dll in your project directory**

That your programm will run successfully it has to find the `*.dll` file at runtime. You can either place it in a folder referenced by the PATH variable, or in the PWD of your process. This would be right beside your `*.vcxproj` files.

If you are linking statically you can skip step 3, if you are loading the dll file dynamically you can skip step 2.

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer. Is there a way in VS2017 to add a runtime directory in the project options to find dlls ? Something like `./bin` or an entirely different directory such as `C:/SomeSDK/bin` ? Basically to avoid copying all dlls. Thanks.

Comment: VS2017 has no Project > Properties > Linker