# How to use SBML library with c++

Tags: visual-c++, mathml, sbml

I want to parse MathML to infix. Post "C Library To Convert Mathml Infix " suggests me to use the [SBML library](http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/docs/cpp-api/index.html). I follow the thread [Link 3rd Party Library In Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008426/link-3rd-party-library-in-visual-studio)'s guildlines to configure my project.
The source code was compiled successfully, but I cannot build the project.

Show output from Build:
1>  Unused libraries:
1>    C:\Users\maiti\Source\Repos\May 25\MathML\SBML\lib\bzip2.lib
1>    C:\Users\maiti\Source\Repos\May 25\MathML\SBML\lib\iconv.lib
1>    C:\Users\maiti\Source\Repos\May 25\MathML\SBML\lib\libsbml.lib
1>    C:\Users\maiti\Source\Repos\May 25\MathML\SBML\lib\libxml2.lib
1>    C:\Users\maiti\Source\Repos\May 25\MathML\SBML\lib\zdll.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\user32.lib
1>    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86\gdi32.lib
...

p.s. sorry I don't have enough reputation to put more links or screenshots on this post

Answer (score 2):

I recommend, that you do you CMake to build libSBML with the examples. There are several examples that show how to deal with MathML for example the translateMath example does convert between MathML and infix.

When you setup the build using CMake, you can specify which parser to use (for example expat would suffice as you only need an XML parser... then the compression and other libraries would not apply).

Some documentation:

- installation:  http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/docs/cpp-api/libsbml-installation.html
- example overview http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/docs/cpp-api/libsbml-example-files.html
- dependencies: There are also compiled dependencies available for different versions of Visual Studio:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/sbml/files/libsbml/win-dependencies/