# How to get start using z3

Tags: c++, visual-studio, z3

I am new to z3. I downloaded the latest version from github and followed the instructions to build using visual studio on windows.
Now, i have to use the z3 c++ APIs in a visual studio project. I imported the code example provided in the package into a new vs project to test it but it can't recognize the z3 header file. Seems that there is some thing missed.
Can anyone guide me in how to use z3 in a vs project?

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030556/linking-third-party-libraries-in-vs-2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual for shared libraries, you have to add the folder that contains `*.h` to your include paths and the folder that contains `*.dll` and `*.lib` files to your library paths. Finally, add `*.lib` to the libraries the linker will link. There are heaps of other questions and solutions for that on stackoverflow, see for instance [How to include libraries in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058864/how-to-include-libraries-in-visual-studio-2012).