# Linking .lib and .h files (OpenJDK 1.8)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, java-deployment-toolkit

I have a project, that includes jni.h and jvmti.h files
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Mza.png)

theese files are stored in jdk8 folder (already installed on my pc)
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cv1j.png)

but the main problem - i dont know how can i correctly link jdk libs and .h files to my visual studio prj

Comment: Just like most 3rd party libraries, add the path to the include folder for your projects "Additional Include Directories" setting. Make sure you apply this change to all configurations and setup the library to the Linker -> Input setting. There are a few duplicats that should help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030556/compiling-and-linking-third-party-libraries-in-vs-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030556/compiling-and-linking-third-party-libraries-in-vs-2015)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could follow the following steps to link the static library:

1,Add the path to the header file to the Additional Include Directories(property - >c/c++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories)

2,Add the path to the .lib file to the Additional Library Directories (property -> linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories)

3,Add the name of the .lib file with its extension to Additional Dependencies (property -> linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies)