# How to get FFTW++ working on windows? (for dummies)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, fftw

I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015. In C++, I need to get the Fourier-transform of an image for applying filters on it. It seems that FFTW++ is the ideal solution for this, however I can't get it to compile, and its driving me mad. I'm relatively new to programming so I don't know how embarrassing this is.

I used the NuGet function in Visual Studio to get the FFTW library.
Since I couldn't find it on NuGet I downloaded the FFTW+ stuff from the following link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/fftwpp/
I copied the content of the download to the project folder, and included the header files in the solution explorer. But it didn't compile, thrown many-many weird errors (for example: in the seconds.h it said that some function which gets the timezone is obsolete, and in the fftww++.h it said that std::max is illegal).

So after seeing that this isn't going to work I went back to the FFTW website, and tried using the Windows installation guide. http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html
I downloaded the 64-bit version, and I have absolutely no idea how to do the library import thing, or even what it does. 
i.imgur.com/Qs7mFQT.png
This is all I get, I'm completely lost.

How can I get it to compile?
Please if you can: write me an explanation as detailed as possible on how to use this thing, I may be dumb but I literally have no idea what is going on, and I can't find any tutorial-like on Google.

Comment: Nowadays you can also use open source library managers like [vckpg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg). Installing an extra prrogram gives an overhead, but it is useful if you are planning to use some other libraries too.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Get the 64bit precompiled FFTW 3.3.5 Windows DLL**

1. Download from [fftw-3.3.5-dll64.zip](ftp://ftp.fftw.org/pub/fftw/fftw-3.3.5-dll64.zip)
2. Unzip the file.

**Create the import library** (.lib file)

1. The official FFTW instructions are [here](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html).
2. For background on how to link a DLL to a Visual Studio C++ program this MSDN article [Linking an Executable to a DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633.aspx) especially the part about **[implicit linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx)** is helpful.
3. Also helpful, in the unzip location, README-WINDOWS.
4. Open the Visual Studio Developer Command prompt

   - Navigate to **Start** -> **All Apps** -> **Visual Studio 2015** -> **Developer Command prompt**
   - On my machine the location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat
5. Navigate to the unzip location and type

   `lib /machine:x64 /def:libfftw3-3.def`

[image: Generate .lib file]

(for single or long-double precision use libfftw3f-3.def or libfftw3l-3.def)

- This will produce libfftw3-3.lib
- Note this is for x64.

**Open Visual Studio and Create a C++ Console Application**

1. Create a C++ Console application
   [image: New visual studio C++ console app]
2. Accept all the default settings
   [image: Keep default settings]
3. Set the solution platform to x64
   [image: x64 platform]

**Tell Visual Studio where to find the FFTW header file.**

(Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4446085/572332) SO answer.)

There are various ways to do this, here is one way.

1. In the solution explorer, right click on the **project** and select properties.
   [image: Project properties]
2. Add additional include directories. This will be the unzip location.
   [image: Additional include directories]

(Alternatively, the .h file can be copied into the Visual Studio project folder.)

**Tell Visual Studio where to find the FFTW import library.**

1. Right click on the project and select properties.
   [image: Project properties]
2. Add additional library directories. This will be the unzip location.
   [image: Additional library directories]
3. Add additional dependency. Type in the .lib file created earlier (libfftw3-3.lib).
   [image: Additional dependency]

**Create a sample program**

(From the [FFTW tutorial](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html#Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs).)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <fftw3.h>

int main()
{
    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan p;

    int N = 32;

    in = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(p); /* repeat as needed */

    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(in); fftw_free(out);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

**Tell Windows where to find the FFTW DLL**
The easiest way is to copy the FFTW DLL (libfftw3-3.dll) from the unzip location to the Visual Studio output folder.

1. In Visual Studio right click on the **solution** and select **Open Folder in File Exporer**.
   [image: Solution in File Explorer]
2. Navigate to the .exe output folder (e.g. fftw_helloworld2\x64\Debug)
   [image: Exe output folder]
3. Copy the DLL libfftw3-3.dll

**Run / Debug**

1. Set a breakpoint
2. Press F5 or
   [image: Start debugger]

Comment: Why must you copy the dlls. Why can't you just statically link with the `.lib`

Comment: LIB files contain just enough code to load a DLL and call its functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62909235

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this, it solved the issue I was having.  Here is my contribution to the answer:

The console application defaults to x86 arch.  I had to use the 32-bit dll from the FFTW folks.  Make sure you specify /machine:x86 when invoking lib
This is with VS2017 community

Ed