# Linux issue happens on Windows? "fatal error: fftw3.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: r

I am running MRO 3.5.0 on Win10, and trying to install a package `image.CannyImage` from `bnosac/image` on the github. But it keeps reporting fatal errors as following.

```
* installing *source* package 'image.CannyEdges' ...
** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/ROPEN~1/R-35~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/eric1/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include"   -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.5.0/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/ROPEN~1/R-35~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/eric1/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include"   -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.5.0/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c adsf.c -o adsf.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/ROPEN~1/R-35~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/eric1/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include"   -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.5.0/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c rcpp_canny.cpp -o rcpp_canny.o
In file included from rcpp_canny.cpp:13:0:
canny.h:8:19: fatal error: fftw3.h: No such file or directory
 #include <fftw3.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1/ROPEN~1/R-35~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:215: rcpp_canny.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'image.CannyEdges'
* removing 'C:/Users/eric1/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/image.CannyEdges'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)

                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

[image]

Google says I can solve the issue by `sudo apt-get remove libfftw3-dev`. Unfortunately, I am on Windows, and some advised, apply `lib /machine:i386 /def:libfftw3-3.def` on cmd mode. Ouch, there is no such command or file called `lib.exe` on Win10.
Please advise, how I can solve this issue on my Win10+MRO system. Thanks.

Comment: If you were using Linux, you would want `sudo apt-get install`, not `sudo apt-get remove`. On Windows, you need to figure out how to get the fftw library installed. [Here are some suggestions](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html). [Here's another guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675436/how-to-get-fftw-working-on-windows-for-dummies) for Visual Studio.

Comment: @neilfws thanks for the advice. I'd never used VS before, just downloaded and follow the instructions one by one. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this question is already a bit old:
By now (Feb 2020) there are precompiled packages available that work also under Windows:

[Canny Edges - Package](https://github.com/bnosac/drat/blob/gh-pages/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/image.CannyEdges_0.1.0.zip)

and more general:

[List of all available packages](https://github.com/bnosac/drat/tree/gh-pages/bin/windows/contrib/3.5)

I have tried installing them and (at least for me) it worked.