VS 2022 & fftw3 Unrecognised external symbol while compiling
I installed Precompiled FFTW 3.3.5 Windows DLLs on my laptop, added in Configuration Properties:
C/C++, General, Additional Include Directories, *"unzip location"
Linker, General, Additional Library Directories, *"unzip location"
Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies, libfftw3-3.lib
and included #include <fftw3.h> in my program.
When I try to compile (Debug) I get: Error C1083 Cannot open include file: fftw3.h: No such file or directory.
For Debug configuration the #include is red underscored, in Release not. When red underscored it advises me to use command command "vcpkg install fftw3:x64-windows".
*Directory of C:\Users\Caster\Downloads\fftw-3.3.5-dll64
26.10.2024  14:53            18 517 fftw3.h
What's the problem and how to fix it?

I don’t use MSVC, but I suspect there might be separate configurations for release and debug. You configured release correctly, but not debug.

Yes, the configs are totally separate, and you have to add the directories to both (or how many configs you have, Debug and Release are not the only possible options, only the default ones).

I wrote the full path to fftw3 #include <... which fixed the problem, although I have the same path set both in C++ and Linker configuration.
While compiling, I got these error warnings:
LNK1120 Number of unrecognized external types: 2
LNK2019 Unrecognised external symbol "void __cdecl IFFT(class std::complex *,int)" (?IFFT@@YAXPEAV?$complex@N@std@@H@Z) referred to in the function "void __cdecl square_using_fft(class std::complex *,int)" (?square_using_fft@@YAXPEAV?$complex@N@std@@H@Z) AVX2_FFT_mult C:\Users\Caster\source\repos\AVX2_FFT_mult\AVX2_FFT_mult\AVX2_FFT_mult.obj

As you explained, in the project properties in Visual Studio, you need to setup the

include directory (C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories),
the linker directory (Linker > General > Additional Library Directories)
and the linker input (i.e. the .lib file) (Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies).

Notably, in your project's properties, you have two dropdowns at the top: "Configuration" and "Platform". By default you have Debug and Release as configuration available, and x86 and Win32 as platform.

The properties can be configured for each pair of configuration and platform individually. So even if you need only x64, ensure that Debug and Release are both setup.
Moreover, at the top of the Visual Studio main window, you can select what you want to build: The configuration and the platform:

Ensure that you build that configuration/platform which you actually configured.
Notes:

Don't write the full path in the #include statement.
Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676354/3740047

