# visual studio 2010 express gtest c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, testing, googletest

I am trying to create a basic test file using gtest but I am getting the error : testvs\debug\testvs.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

test.cpp

```
#include <gtest\gtest.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

TEST(test_case,simple_case)
{
    int i=0;
    int b=1;
    int result= i*b;
    int expected=0;
    EXPECT_EQ(result,expected);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <gtest\gtest.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc,argv);
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

when I comment out the lines

```
TEST(test_case,simple_case)
{
    int i=0;
    int b=1;
    int result= i*b;
    int expected=0;
    EXPECT_EQ(result,expected);
}
```

and

```
::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc,argv);
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();
```

it does not give any error. 
Please help

Comment: Have you added the include files and the lib files in your project? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-in-c

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez yes