# How to fix this error which comes building the VirtualplannetBuilder source on visual studio 2013?

Tags: c++, gdal, openscenegraph

I already installed GDAL 1.11.4 32Bit and OpenSceneGraph-3.4.0 on my windows 10 machine.

```
1>gdal.lib(cpl_odbc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLAllocConnect@8 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CPLODBCSession::EstablishSession(char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?EstablishSession@CPLODBCSession@@QAEHPBD00@Z)
    1>gdal.lib(cpl_odbc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLAllocEnv@4 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CPLODBCSession::EstablishSession(char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?EstablishSession@CPLODBCSession@@QAEHPBD00@Z)
    1>gdal.lib(cpl_odbc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLAllocStmt@8 referenced in function "public: __thiscall CPLODBCStatement::CPLODBCStatement(class CPLODBCSession *)" (??0CPLODBCStatement@@QAE@PAVCPLODBCSession@@@Z)
    1>gdal.lib(cpl_odbc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLColAttribute@28 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CPLODBCStatement::CollectResultsInfo(void)" (?CollectResultsInfo@CPLODBCStatement@@QAEHXZ)
    1>gdal.lib(cpl_odbc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLColumns@36 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CPLODBCStatement::GetColumns(char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?GetColumns@CPLODBCStatement@@QAEHPBD00@Z)
    1>gdal.lib(cpl_odbc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLConnect@28 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CPLODBCSession::EstablishSession(char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?EstablishSession@CPLODBCSession@@QAEHPBD00@Z)
    1>gdal.lib(cpl_odbc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLDescribeCol@36 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CPLODBCStatement::CollectResultsInfo(void)" (?CollectResultsInfo@CPLODBCStatement@@QAEHXZ)
    1>gdal.lib(cpl_odbc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLDisconnect@4 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall CPLODBCSession::CloseSession(void)" (?CloseSession@CPLODBCSession@@QAEHXZ)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link with the appropriate library. I seem to remember that you, in this case, need either `ODBC32.lib` or `ODBCCP32.lib`, or both libraries.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-do-i-add-additional-libraries-in-c) is answer on how to add additional libraries.

Comment: fixed the error after adding both files to the additional dependencies.(ODBC32.lib and ODBCCP32.lib.)