# Building GSL (GNU Scientific Library) in Windows for use with VS2015

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, mingw, gsl

I am trying to build GSL as a library(DLL,lib) to use with my application. I have tested both GSL ports(gladman) to VS and CMake route and I do not want to go that path due to various reasons.

Currently I am using nuget version and I am not too happy about it as some functions are missing. I want to build it myself to be absolutely sure about what I am getting. The objective is to build four set of dll and libs---win32, win32d, win64 and win64d.

I know that from a MinGW library I can build lib file(for VS2015) and thereafter dll using  Microsoft LIB tool if I have DEF file available.

My open source experience is very limited. Till now I have successfully built gsl for MinGW using ./config, make, make install. But I am not finding any DEF file generated and I do not know how to utilize this build to generate required DEF and dll to be used with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Building and linking has always been a pain for me as well. For mac, I use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), which **downloads frameworks and libraries through a simple one-line-command in the terminal**. I would then simply add the library into my program by adding the directory of the libs necessary. In XCode, there was an "add framework/library"-button where I added the directories, but I'm sure there's an analogue in VS.

However, you seem to be using Windows (so Homebrew will not work). I searched the web for Windows versions of Homebrew, and it seems that [Scoop](http://scoop.sh/) is pretty similar. You might want to check that out.

Hope this helped, despite me using different tools :)

Comment: Thanks Simon, will surely help when I build in Mac as my application is cross platform. But I need to build for windows myself as I need to take care of debug, versioning, distribution and licenses as well.

Comment: Perhaps the accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-do-i-add-additional-libraries-in-c) will allow you to successfully add your library. Try that solution in combination with Scoop. I believe Scoop downloads everything to your home directory, so the added directory should be something like **<whatever-HOME-means-in-windows>/<whatever-the-downloaded-lib-folder-name-is>**. Best of luck :)