# Build error on Visual Studio 2013 (Windows 7-64bit) while connecting to connector C libraries of MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-c

Need Help:

I need to connect to MySQL 5.7 using connector/C on visual studio 2013 using a basic C program. I am getting errors linked to my_global.h.

I tried to find the solution on google but I am unsucessful yet.

My Steps:

1. I downloaded MySQL 5.7 from MySQL webpage, and installed its msi installer sucessfully.
2. I downloaded its Connector/C from MySQL webpage and installed its msi installer sucessfully. I found out that Connector/C is composed of header files (include files) and a library file (libmysql).
3. I followed this  [tutorial (stackoverflow supported answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-do-i-add-additional-libraries-in-c)to link library and include files into Visual Studio 2013.
4. I write the following code on Visual Studio 2013

> ```
> #include <my_global.h>
> #include <mysql.h>
>
> int main(int argc, char **argv)
> {
>   MYSQL *conn;
>   conn = mysql_init(NULL);
>
>   if (conn == NULL)
>   {
>       printf("Error %u %s\n", mysql_errno(conn), mysql_error(conn));
>       exit(1);
>   }
>
>   if (mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "asdfasdf", NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
>   {
>       printf("Error %u: %s\n", mysql_errno(conn), mysql_error(conn));
>       exit(1);
>   }
>
>   if (mysql_query(conn, "CREATE DATABASE testdb"))
>   {
>       printf("Error %u: %s", mysql_errno(conn), mysql_error(conn));
>       exit(1);
>   }
>
>   mysql_close(conn);
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

**It gives error: 
Error   2   error C2037: left of 'tv_nsec' specifies undefined struct/union 'timespec'  c:\program files\mysql\mysql connector c 6.1\include\my_global.h    698 1   mysql**

Can you help in following matters:

1. I searched on google and was unable to find any specific tutorial. I searched google, youtube and stackoverflow. The [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/preface.html) isn't helping on getting started. Can you suggest me and support me in this problem?
2. Is there any 1 (just one) ebook or book available on Connecting to MySQL using C programming?

I will be thankful for help!

Answer (score 0):

The linking method is absolutely correct.
I also installed server mysql. I linked the mysql server libraries and it worked fine.