# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'curl.lib'

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, lib

when I enter `error.h` file from `rapidjson` file and when I build error appears (

> LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file `cur.lib`)

anyone can help me

[image: error view]
[image: code in question]

```
#ifndef RAPIDJSON_ERROR_ERROR_H_
#define RAPIDJSON_ERROR_ERROR_H_

#include "../rapidjson.h"

#ifdef __clang__
RAPIDJSON_DIAG_PUSH
RAPIDJSON_DIAG_OFF(padded)
#endif

Another code exists in rapidjson / include / error / error.h
I can not enter more code here
```

Comment: Screenshots and question text do not match. *"cur.lib"* vs. *"curl.lib"*, which one is it?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4446085/6610379) should help.