# [CURL][VS2017] error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_global_init referenced

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors, libcurl

I followed the tutorial here on this to **add libcurl to my VS project**

http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2018/03/13/using-curl-library-from-c-on-windows/

After following all the steps still i get below linking errors.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_global_init referenced
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_init referenced in function
```

Its 5 hours trying same,but still cant resolve.Please help!!

Comment: You should link to ``curl`` static libraries

Comment: i have done as below already 
Add CURL_STATICLIB to the preprocessor definitions.

Comment: Add curl.lib to the [link library list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-do-i-add-additional-libraries-in-c)

Comment: This is also done
Add the following static libraries to the list of Additional dependencies: libcurld.lib;Crypt32.lib;ws2_32.lib;winmm.lib;wldap32.lib;

Comment: Try `dumpbin.exe /SYMBOLS libcurld.lib` and check the presence of the symbol