# Include DIPlib library C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, shared-libraries, diplib

This might seem like an obvious problem, but I'm struggling to include the [DIPlib library](http://www.diplib.org/diplib) into my C++ project.

I'm using Windows 10, 64-Bit and CLion (or alternatively Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise with R#). I'm currently using CMake, but I'd be open to other solutions as well.

However, I could only find a download link for the DIPimage package (which seems to be an installer).
I did already install this, but I (obviously) still can't use the library in my project.

I simply couldn't find a way to include this type of library.

The documentation does however mention some include files to include, which I found in the *dipimage_2.9_win64.zip*, but how am I supposed to include these? Or do I have to include the *libdip.dll*, which can be found in the same zip?

Comment: What does the documentation for Diplib say? I'd start by looking at the sample gcc line they provided. Did the installation create this directory and these files? ftp://qiftp.tudelft.nl/DIPimage/docs/standalone.c

Comment: It also looks like the have a snazzy pdf. Did you read it? ftp://qiftp.tudelft.nl/DIPimage/latest/docs/diplib_programmers_guide.pdf

Comment: @ChristopherPisz The installation of the library seemed to be obvious to them, as I couldn't find anything regarding the topic (http://www.diplib.org/documentation). And yes, I roughly read the pdf which, as mentioned, doesn't seem to regard the installation process. It does mention some include files to include, which I found in the dipimage_2.9_win64.zip, but how am I supposed to include these? Or do I have to include the .dll, which can be found in the same zip?

Comment: I dunno where you are at, so forgive if this is way too obvious, but typically, a library consists of a .lib or a lib and a .dll file and a .h file or many .h files. If you have those in hand, and you know they are 32 bit or 64 bit windows, then you just need to know how to set up linkage in visual studio. Are you at that point?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz yes, I think I have those files.

Comment: Then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-do-i-add-additional-libraries-in-c is probably relevant to you. Link to the .lib, include the includes in your source, and put the dll in the output directory next to your .exe

Comment: Considering that you are using C++, I recommend that you jump over to DIPlib 3. It is not officially released yet, but it’s fairly stable at this point and being used in serious work by quite a few folk. https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib