# Crypto++ CRC32 linker errór

Tags: c++, windows, linker-errors, crc, crypto++

I tried to compile an application to encrypt some files, but I have a problem when I try to compile. Everything looks good, but I don't know why I get this error.

My error is:

```
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CryptoPP::CRC32::CRC32(void)" (??0CRC32@CryptoPP@@QAE@XZ)  FoxFs   C:\Users\lazar\Desktop\eph2_live_src\Sources\X_thirdparty_src\FoxFS\FoxFS\FoxFS\ArchiveWriter.obj   1
```

And my code/line with problems as well:

```
CryptoPP::CRC32 crc;
crc.CalculateDigest(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&index), reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(fname.c_str()), fname.length());
```

My full code:

```
#include "ArchiveWriter.h"
#include "../src/config.h"

#include "../cryptopp/modes.h"
#include "../cryptopp/aes.h"
#include "../cryptopp/crc.h"
#include "../cryptopp/osrng.h"
#include <boost/crc.hpp>

#pragma comment( lib, "cryptopp.lib" )

ArchiveWriter::ArchiveWriter()
{
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
    keys = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    file = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
#else
    keys = -1;
    file = -1;
#endif
}
ArchiveWriter::~ArchiveWriter() { close(); }

bool ArchiveWriter::create(const char* filename, const char* keyfile)
{
    close();
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
    unsigned char key[32], iv[32];
    FoxFS::TArchiveHeader header;
    header.magic = FOXFS_MAGIC;
    rng.GenerateBlock(header.key, 32);
    rng.GenerateBlock(header.iv, 32);
    rng.GenerateBlock(key, 32);
    rng.GenerateBlock(iv, 32);
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
    if (keyfile)
    {
        keys = CreateFileA(keyfile, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
        if (keys == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    file = CreateFileA(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (keys != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            CloseHandle(keys);
            keys = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
        }
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwWritten;
    WriteFile(file, &header, sizeof(header), &dwWritten, 0);
    if (keys != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // write magic number?
        WriteFile(keys, key, 32, &dwWritten, 0);
        WriteFile(keys, iv, 32, &dwWritten, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(this->key)[i] = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(key)[i] ^ reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(header.key)[i];
            reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(this->iv)[i] = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(iv)[i] ^ reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(header.iv)[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(this->key, header.key, 32);
        memcpy(this->iv, header.iv, 32);
    }
#else
    if (keyfile)
    {
        keys = ::open(keyfile, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH);
        if (keys == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    file = ::open(filename, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH);
    if (file == -1)
    {
        if (keys != -1)
        {
            ::close(keys);
            keys = -1;
        }
        return false;
    }

    write(file, &header, sizeof(header));
    if (keys != -1)
    {
        // write magic number?
        write(keys, key, 32);
        write(keys, iv, 32);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(this->key)[i] = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(key)[i] ^ reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(header.key)[i];
            reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(this->iv)[i] = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(iv)[i] ^ reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(header.iv)[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(this->key, header.key, 32);
        memcpy(this->iv, header.iv, 32);
    }
#endif
    return true;
}
void ArchiveWriter::close()
{
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
    if (keys != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(keys);
        keys = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
    if (file != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(file);
        file = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
#else
    if (keys != -1)
    {
        ::close(keys);
        keys = -1;
    }
    if (file != -1)
    {
        ::close(file);
        file = -1;
    }
#endif
}

bool ArchiveWriter::add(const char* filename, unsigned int decompressed, unsigned int compressed, unsigned int hash, const void* data)
{
    unsigned int index = 0;
    std::string fname = filename;
    transform(fname.begin(), fname.end(), fname.begin(), tolower);
    for (int i = 0; i < fname.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (fname[i] == '\\')
        {
            fname[i] = '/';
        }
    }

    CryptoPP::CRC32 crc;
    crc.CalculateDigest(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&index), reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(fname.c_str()), fname.length());

    unsigned short namelen = strlen(filename);
    FoxFS::TArchiveEntry entry;
    entry.decompressed = decompressed;
    entry.hash = hash;
    entry.offset = sizeof(entry);
    entry.size = compressed;
    entry.name = index;

    std::string fn = filename;
    transform(fn.begin(), fn.end(), fn.begin(), tolower);
    for (int i = 0; i < fn.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (fn[i] == '\\')
        {
            fn[i] = '/';
        }
    }

    CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption encoder(this->key, 32, this->iv);
    encoder.ProcessData(const_cast<unsigned char*>(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data)), reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data), compressed);

#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64)
    DWORD dwWritten;
    WriteFile(keys, &namelen, sizeof(namelen), &dwWritten, 0);
    WriteFile(keys, filename, namelen, &dwWritten, 0);
    WriteFile(keys, &hash, sizeof(hash), &dwWritten, 0);

    LARGE_INTEGER m, p;
    m.QuadPart = 0;
    SetFilePointerEx(file, m, &p, FILE_CURRENT);

    entry.offset += p.QuadPart;

    WriteFile(file, &entry, sizeof(entry), &dwWritten, 0);
    WriteFile(file, data, compressed, &dwWritten, 0);
#else
    write(keys, &namelen, sizeof(namelen));
    write(keys, filename, namelen);
    write(keys, &hash, sizeof(hash));

    entry.offset += lseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR);

    write(file, &entry, sizeof(entry));
    write(file, data, compressed);
#endif
    return true;
}
```

If remove the `Cryptopp::CRC32 crc` and next layer, my building works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: This is a lot of code. You'll get better answers if you produce the smallest possible program that produces your error.

Comment: Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #include "../cryptopp/crc.h"
> ...
>
> #pragma comment( lib, "cryptopp.lib" )
> ```

On Windows the static library name is `cryptlib.lib`. `cryptopp.lib` was used for the FIPS DLL, but you are probably not using it. Also see [Visual Studio](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Visual_Studio) and [FIPS DLL](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FIPS_DLL) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Runtime linker settings usually gives folks some trouble. Be sure to visit [Runtime Linking](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Visual_Studio#Runtime_Linking) on the Crypto++ wiki, too.

You may have other problems, but we need to see the compile and link commands you are using along with the errors. I suspect you need to add an [Additional Linker Path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4445418/608639) so `cryptlib.lib` is found, but I need to see your commands and the errors.