# Linker errors using FMT for string interpolation in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, fmt

I am trying to use [FTM](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) for string interpolation in C++ but it is giving me some linker errors when I try to compile.

I have written the following class:

```
#include <string>
#include "include/fmt/format.h"

class A {
public:
    std::string sayHi(std::string name) {
        return fmt::format("Hello {0}", name);
    }
};
```

Using this class in my main results in some LNK2001 en LNK2019 errors. Here is a small sample of them:
[image]
I am guessing this is due to incorrect usage of the library. Am I missing some global variable that should be set?

Comment: You need to *link* against libfmt.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "link against" does not really give a result searching for it or on the link you mentioned this is a duplicate of. It might make sense in the context of c++ but I am not an experienced c++ programmer.

Comment: First, you need to [build libfmt with CMake](https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake%20build%20with%20visual%20stdio). It should give you `fmt.lib` or a similarly named file. Then you specify a path to this file [somewhere in your project settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks. I'll look into that next.