# How do you install NPCap library into Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, import, npcap

I am trying to install the NPCap library into Visual Studio so I can run this code from the documentation.

```
#include "pcap.h"

main()
{
pcap_if_t* alldevs;
pcap_if_t* d;
int i = 0;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

/* Retrieve the device list from the local machine */
if (pcap_findalldevs_ex(PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING, NULL /* auth is not needed */, &alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in pcap_findalldevs_ex: %s\n", errbuf);
    exit(1);
}

/* Print the list */
for (d = alldevs; d != NULL; d = d->next)
{
    printf("%d. %s", ++i, d->name);
    if (d->description)
        printf(" (%s)\n", d->description);
    else
        printf(" (No description available)\n");
}

if (i == 0)
{
    printf("\nNo interfaces found! Make sure Npcap is installed.\n");
    return;
}

/* We don't need any more the device list. Free it */
pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
```

}
When I run this code I get many errors, one of which is `"cannot open source file "pcap/pcap.h"`. The other errors state that the variables are undefined. I believe I have not installed the library correctly.

I have both the .lib files and the .h files in the same directory in my desktop, as can be seen in this screenshot.

[image: directory]

I have also changed the directories in Visual Studio to the appropriate folder.

[image: change1]

[image: change2]

As per the instructions found in: [How to add additional libraries to Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project)

Comment: Probably either OneDrive or copying all the files to a single directory.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I am working with Npcap and it takes me several hours to set it up in VS. Following is the way works for me.

1. Download **Npcap SDK** from [here](https://npcap.com/) in section "Downloading and Installing Npcap Free Edition". Unzip it to directory you want. In the folder you will see folder "Lib" and "Include", remember them.
2. Open your Visual Studio and right click on your project in Solution Explorer and then **Properties**.

- Open **Configuration Properties** and go to **C/C++**.
  In **General** choose **Additional Include Directories**. In this option add path to folder "Include".
- Choose option **Linker** and then **General** 
  Select **Additional Library Directory Directories**. Here you need to add path to folder "x64" under folder "Lib".
- Still under option **Linker** choose **Input**.
  Select **Additional Dependencies** and at here you will add file names under folder "x64". On my computer they are "Packet.lib" and "wpcap.lib".

Here we have set Npcap in VS.
As a reference, please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project) on SO. BTW, if "#include <pcap.h>" does not work, try "#include <pcap/pcap.h>" instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I have both the .lib files and the .h files in the same directory in my desktop

Don't do that.  Just extract the Npcap SDK, and leave the files in the directories in which the Npcap SDK puts them.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77698219/16139739) for information on how to use that SDK.

Answer (score 0):

From the error

> "cannot open source file "pcap/pcap.h"

it looks like it is expecting a directory structure. Directory named "pcap" with all the header files in it.

Can you confirm you added this folder path in Library Directory as well.
Link for reference.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcpp-directories-property-page?view=vs-2019
2. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-include-libraries-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: "it looks like it is expecting a directory structure. Directory named "pcap" with all the header files in it." Yes, libpcap/Npcap puts all of its headers in a "pcap" directory, with a "pcap.h" header in the top-level include directory that includes "pcap/pcap.h", for source code compatibility with older versions of libpcap.