# namespace pqxx not recognized - Issues adding libpqxx to C++ Visual Studio PostgreSQL project on Windows

Tags: c++, postgresql, visual-studio, cmake, libpqxx

**The Issue**

I'm trying to use lipqxx to interact with a PostgreSQL database. However, despite #include-ing pqxx, its namespace doesn't seem to be recognized and as such no pqxx functions are recognized. (simplified code with annotations of issue below:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx> // no errors indicated in Visual Studio (VS) here. 

void Classname::operator() (){ // functor method implementation
    using namespace std;
    using namespace pqxx; // **red underline in Visual Studio indicating "name must be a namespace"**
    try{
        connection C("String text"); // **red underline in VS: "identifier 'connection' is undefined"**
    }catch(const std::exception &e) {
        cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**What I've done**

1. Downloaded CMake (for Windows) and libpqxx.
2. Built lipqxx using CMake following instructions in (this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxHV-KNEG3k). This produced a folder called "libpqxx" which has "bin", "include", "lib" and "share" sub-folders.
3. Followed instructions (on this thread: [How to add additional libraries to Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project)) to add the built libraries to my VS project

**Conclusion**

I'd like the pqxx namespace to be properly recognized and am not sure where to go from here. I've been stuck on this for quite a while and would really appreciate some clear guiding steps on how to fix this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem after running:

```
vcpkg install libqpxx:x64-windows
```

Running (as administrator)

```
vcpkg integrate install
```

solved the issue for me

Comment: Could you correct your answer so I can select it as the best one. I had tried vcpkg to no avail but they appeared to update the bugs! now it works seamlessly but your instructions are incorrect. They should be: "vcpkg install libpqxx:x64-windows" and "vcpkg integrate install"

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution to this by adding the folder called "include" (located within the "libpqxx" directory that was produced by the CMake process) to the Visual Studio Project using

**Project** -> **Properties** -> **C/C++** -> **General** -> **Additional Include Directories** -> **edit** (*drop-down option*) -> **New Line** (*icon*) -> *browse to and select the "include" folder* -> **OK**

The #include error disappeared but I then received the following errors (snippet below) after trying to compile my program:

> 1>D:\Software\libpqxx\libpqxx\include\pqxx\internal\encoding_group.hxx(14,1): error C2429:  language feature 'nested-namespace-definition' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'

I solved these by setting the Visual Studio C++ Language property of the project to C++ 17 via:

**Project** -> **Properties** -> **C/C++** -> **Language** -> **C++ Language Standard** -> (*select drop-down option)* **ISO C++ 17 Standard (/std:c++17)**

---

### EDIT: (Cleanest Solution by Far)

The cleanest solution is to use Microsoft's [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg#quick-start-windows) package installer because it **very simply** adds libpqxx to Visual Studio itself, and not to individual projects on a per-project basis.

As explained via the instructions on the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg#quick-start-windows):

1. **Install vcpkg** by running the below commands in cmd from a folder called C:\src (to avoid issues. Create folder if necessary):

> `git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg`
>
> `.\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`

2. **Install libpqxx** by entering in cmd from the same folder:

> `.\vcpkg\vcpkg install libpqxx:x64-windows`
>
> `.\vcpkg\vcpkg integrate install`
>
> `.\vcpkg\vcpkg install libpqxx`

3. **All done!**