# namespace pqxx not recognized in my c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense, vcpkg, libpqxx

I have a project in c++. I have successfully installed pqxx package using vcpkg but still namespace 'pqxx' is not recognized,

```
#include<pqxx/pqxx>  //No errors
using namespace pqxx; //Error, 'name must be a namespace name'
```

Comment: Is that an error from the compiler or from the code completion in your IDE?

Comment: @AlanBirtles the error is from code completion on visual studio IDE

Comment: Does the compiler work? If so just ignore intellisense, sometimes it gets confused (unless you're using vscode? The intellisense configuration is separate from the compiler configuration)

Comment: The compiler does not work since functions of pqxx are throwing errors because namespace is not recognized

Comment: Have you configured your projects to use the library?

Comment: Yes I have added include folder to 'C/C++\General\Additional Include Directories' but still not change

Comment: Yes, the project is configured well

Comment: Are you sure you've changed the active configuration?

Comment: i am using Win32 as target platform

Comment: But are you sure you've alerted the same configuration that you're building? It's radio enough to accidentally set the wrong one in vs

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860307/namespace-pqxx-not-recognized-issues-adding-libpqxx-to-c-visual-studio-postg) can help you. It looks like a similar problem.