# What is the proper way of adding GLFW?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, cmake, glfw

[This tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window), after the whole CMake build thing which I have done but not necessarily understand why its like that, it says the following:

> Once we generated the library we need to make sure the IDE knows where
>   to find the library and the include files for our OpenGL program.
>   There are two common approaches in doing this:
>
> 1. We find the /lib and /include folders of the IDE/compiler and add the content of GLFW's include folder to the IDE's /include folder and
>      similarly add glfw3.lib to the IDE's /lib folder. This works, but it's
>      is not the recommended approach. It's hard to keep track of your
>      library and include files and a new installation of your IDE/compiler
>      results in you having to do this process all over again.
> 2. Another approach (and recommended) is to create a new set of directories at a location of your choice that contains all the header
>      files/libraries from third party libraries to which you can refer to
>      from your IDE/compiler. You could, for instance, create a single
>      folder that contains a Libs and Include folder where we store all our
>      library and header files respectively for OpenGL projects. Now all the
>      third party libraries are organized within a single location (that can
>      be shared across multiple computers). The requirement is, however,
>      that each time we create a new project we have to tell the IDE where
>      to find those directories.

Now I don't exactly understand either methods and how I would go about this. I wanted to try the recommended approach. What would be the best location for these 'Directory' folder, and which of the elements of 'glfw-3.3.2' folder would I put here? And how would I know how to tell the IDE where to find those directories? Is there any single easy-to understand place to get this information on how to properly manage this? I am working with visual studio 2017 community.

Comment: ***What would be the best location for these 'Directory' folder***  This is more of a user preference. For me I structure my folders in a hierarchy. And do this in drive that contains only programming.

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project)

Comment: The linked tutorial explains every step you need to take to link with the libraries. Just keep reading.

Comment: @churill I tried to follow it. It has the what to do for the include folder but then it says 'The same applies for the library directories.' I tried to look for something with .lib in glfw-3.3.2 folder but I don't find anything like that?

Comment: The lib should be in the build folder you created and compiled using Visual Studio. Did you open and compile the solution in build folder?

Comment: @drescherjm I got a bunch of vcsproj files, cmake files, and folders such as CMakeFiles, example, src, tests in my build folder. There is no .lib files anywhere?

Comment: Did you open that project in Visual Studio and build it? In this case `CMake` is generating `Visual Studio` project files that you need to build.

Comment: In this step: ***Since CMake generated a project file that already contains the proper configuration settings we only have to build the solution.*** you need to open the VS project and build it for all configurations.