# How to Link a Library with Visual Studio MSVC

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker

I'm trying to use OpenSSL in my .C file, the include lines look like this:

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
```

However, I get the error:

```
openssl/conf.h: no file or directory
```

The library is located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL" and its include files are located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL\include". How do I link this library while compiling with MSVC?

Comment: Have you specified [additional include directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=msvc-160) ?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield This fixes the include errors, however now I cant seem to link the library. I get: error LNK2019 un resolver external symbol referenced in function main.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4446085/500276) answer

Comment: @MarkBenningfield unfortunately my folder is not a project, is there anyway to do this directly from command line? Thanks again.