# {fmt} How to install and use fmtlib in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, visual-studio-2022, fmt

I am trying to install [fmtlib](https://fmt.dev/) and I have downloaded the zip folder and extracted it, what do I do next to use it in my Visual Studio 2022 project? Because it's my first time installing an external library. Im using windows 10.

Comment: [Nuget is always an option](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fmt/)

Comment: I did that easily with vcpkg: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

Comment: You do know that VS 2022 has `std::format` in the `<format>` header, right?

Comment: I believe fmtlib is header only. You can just add the unzipped folder to your includes.

Comment: @BoP `std::format` is very much lacking compared to the actual fmt library.

Comment: @Felierix  Glad it worked! I added it as an answer if you want to accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have downloaded and extracted the fmtlib, Open Visual Studio and create new project [New Project -> Console App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8bDQ.png)
replace the application file where main method is present with below code.

First line (#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY) is mandatory, which tells compiler to compile fmt header file also.

```
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/color.h>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    fmt::print(fmt::emphasis::bold | fg(fmt::color::red),
        "Elapsed time: {0:.2f} seconds", 1.23);
}
```

Go to Properties of project [Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GToVM.png), and click on dropdown of Include Directories as shown in screenshot.

Click on New Line folder [Folder Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84IZA.png) and click on line to edit and browse folder path of include directory (C:\Users\username\Downloads\fmt-8.1.0\fmt-8.1.0\include)[Browse till include directory of fmt lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHET4.png).

Cross check the path is added [Confirm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mllcc.png).

Now build the Project and Execute code. [Colorful Text Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwxus.png)

Happy Coding!

Comment: Maybe it's better to specify the define in the compiler command line with `/DFMT_HEADER_ONLY`. However I'd avoid to recompile the library each time.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to build the lib with CMake, then you will get the .lib files.
Then you simply add the Header files in the include folder to your project in Visual Studio and link the .lib files to your project like here described:

[How to add additional libraries to Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project)

Comment: How to build the library is also described on the website of the library itself: https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe fmtlib is header only. You can just add the unzipped folder to your includes.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable C++ latest as your C++ Language Standard (latest) in properties, C++, language, you don't need fmtlib.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't have features like fmt color? I think.