# How to add a library extracted from a project into a new Visual Studio project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

An open source project refactored their code to make a library separate from the UI. They made the library available as folders extracted from an IDE project. For the Windows download the folders contain dll, libs, and other files. Below is link to the library download and also summary of the contents.

The limited help i found through internet search and in books about Visual Studio has not enabled me to successfully add this library to a Visual Studio project and use. Can someone look at what was provided and describe what needs to be done to add the library and associate files to a Visual Studio project and use? If it is relevant i am using Visual Studio 2017/2019.

https://github.com/sfztools/sfizz/releases/tag/1.2.3

```
\sfizz-1.2.3-win64\bin\Release
sfizz.dll
sfizz_render.exe
sfizz_tests.exe

\sfizz-1.2.3-win64\lib\Release
absl_bad_optional_access.lib
absl_bad_variant_access.lib
absl_base.lib
...
sfizz_spline.lib 
sfizz_static.lib
sfizz_tunings.lib
st_audiofile.lib 
st_audiofile_formats.lib
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-to-visual-studio-project

Comment: Also, what doesn't work for you? Please edit the question and elaborate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.