I am getting (error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol) in c++ sdl2 project
Hi i am learning c++ and recently i try to use sdl library. i learn the basic from the wiki site but when i try to run my basic template it is giving me  error "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol". I do not  understand what i do wrong.
The Full Error:
1>Oyun.cpp
1>Oyun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_GetError referenced in function SDL_main
1>Oyun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_MapRGB referenced in function SDL_main
1>Oyun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_FillRect referenced in function SDL_main
1>Oyun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_CreateWindow referenced in function SDL_main
1>Oyun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_GetWindowSurface referenced in function SDL_main
1>Oyun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_UpdateWindowSurface referenced in function SDL_main
1>Oyun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_DestroyWindow referenced in function SDL_main
1>Oyun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_PollEvent referenced in function SDL_main
1>Oyun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_Init referenced in function SDL_main
1>Oyun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_Quit referenced in function SDL_main
1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

The Full Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

// Screen Size
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Rendering the Window
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    // Surface inside Window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    // Screen Size
    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

    //Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Oyun", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (window == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        }

        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

            //Fill the surface
            SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));

            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

            //Get window to stay up
            SDL_Event e; bool isRunning = true; while (isRunning == true) { while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) { if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) isRunning = false; } }
        }
    }
    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}


This is all things i have. I am using Visual Studio and i insert both library and include from project settings.
Its prob. because of the main fuctions arguments but i can not figure it out. And AI also do not help me well
I only Change 'Additional Include Directories' and 'Additional Library Directories' in Project Properties to my sdl file include and library. Nothing else, others are in defould settings.
Image 1
Image 2

It's not enough to specify a directory with .libs in it. You have to specify individual .libs as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4446085/2752075

Thank you very much, my friend! This fixed my problem.
